# std::map properties - C+ standard requirements?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, standards, undefined-behavior

Hello and good day to you.

Is this true (is it required by standard) that standard C++ `std::map<Key, Value>` class is required to have following properties:

- It can work if *Value* has no `operator=` or `operator=` is private (and `std::map` is not a private friend of *Value*).
- It can work if *Value* has no default constructor or default constructor is private (and `std::map` is not a private friend of *Value*)

Why I'm asking - I've been asked to write a drop-in replacement for the class that has been using std::map internally. IN process it turned out the class is supposed to work without `operator=` (as long as you avoid `map[key] = value;`). I nuked the `operator=` requirment, but it turned out that using default constructors for *Value* also caused some problems (o_O), because class that was supposed to be *Value* had no default constructors. So... are those standard properties of `std::map`, or was the original class relying on implementation-specific/undefined behavior? I checked "C++ Standard - ANSI ISO IEC 14882 2003", and I couldn't find any of such requirements. I can probably also nuke "default constructor requirement" (as long as user avoids certain calls, such as calling `map[key]` for non-existent key), but I certainly haven't heard about such properties of std::map before...

So... what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my reading of the Standard (**23.2.4 [associative.reqmts]** in C++11, but was already holding in C++03), `V` being `DefaultConstructible` and `V` being `CopyAssignable` are not mandatory requirements for instantiating the container itself, but only to use some of its operations.

However in C++03, `V` must be `CopyConstructible` for all standard containers. Unconditionally. In C++11, this requirement is lifted because one can use the new `emplace*` methods to build an object in place directly.

Comment: Does standard (C++03) specify which operations require `V` being `DefaultConstructible`?

Comment: `map[key]` requires default constructor, because if `key` is not present, a default-constructed instance will be inserted in the map. - This code-path needs to exist, even if never taken at runtime.

Comment: @SigTerm: yes, actually each operation will detail exactly what are the requirements the various need to obey (on top of the general requirements). Most of the times though, they can be inferred with a little of logic :)

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Yes, i know that it is possible to figure out, but in case when you design a drop-in replacement it will be a better idea to stick to documentation. Anyway, I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: @SigTerm: if you don't have the Standard, I suggest using the [SGI STL documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/) it's not exactly what was standardized (there are classes like `rope` that never made it) but for the classes that do made it into the Standard, it should help you tremendously.